# AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'create_mountain'

Tags: python, attributeerror, python-turtle

I'm creating a flappy bird style game using the turtle module in PyCharm. Mountains and clouds move across the screen, created from classes. This issue was not here 2 days ago and I feel as though I've tried everything to solve it. Haven't changed the part of the code this applies to, it only appeared after writing an unrelated "if" statement.

Here's the code from **main.py** file:

```
from turtle import Screen
from flappybird import Bird
from cloud_manager import Cloud
from mountain_manager import Mountain
from ground_manager import Ground
import time

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(800, 400)
screen.bgcolor("light blue")
screen.title("FloppyBird")
screen.tracer(0)

benny = Bird()
ground = Ground()
mountain = Mountain()
cloud = Cloud()


screen.listen()
screen.onkey(benny.go_up, "Up")
screen.onkey(benny.go_down, "Down")


game_on = True
while game_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()

    mountain.create_mountain()
    mountain.move_mountain()

    cloud.create_cloud()
    cloud.move_cloud()
```

and here's the code from **cloud_manager.py** file:

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

MOVE_SPEED = 10


class Cloud:

    def __init__(self):
        self.all_clouds = []
        self.cloud_speed = MOVE_SPEED

    def create_cloud(self):
        random_chance = random.randint(1, 40)
        if random_chance == 1:
            new_cloud = Turtle("circle")
            new_cloud.color("white")
            new_cloud.shapesize(stretch_wid=random.randint(1, 4), stretch_len=random.randint(4, 7))
            new_cloud.penup()
            random_y = random.randint(-70, 175)
            new_cloud.goto(400, random_y)
            self.all_clouds.append(new_cloud)

    def move_cloud(self):
        for cloud in self.all_clouds:
            cloud.backward(self.cloud_speed)
```

It's also not working for the mountain_manager.py file but it's essentially the same code as cloud_manager.py. I'm new here and would appreciate any help. This is my first project not from a tutorial.

edit: added **mountain.py** file:

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

MOVE_SPEED = 10
MOUNTAIN_START = (400, -83)


class Mountain:

    def __init__(self):
        self.all_mounts = []
        self.mountain_speed = MOVE_SPEED

    def create_mountain(self):
        random_chance = random.randint(1, 40)
        if random_chance == 1:
            new_mountain = Turtle("triangle")
            new_mountain.color("tan")
            new_mountain.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=8)
            new_mountain.penup()
            new_mountain.tilt(90)
            new_mountain.goto(MOUNTAIN_START)
            self.all_mounts.append(new_mountain)

    def move_mountain(self):
        for mountain in self.all_mounts:
            mountain.backward(self.mountain_speed)
```

Comment: can you include the code for the Mountain class? You included the Cloud class but the error is for the Mountain. The error is telling you that you have not defined a method (function) called create_mountain() within the Mountain class

Comment: totally. added the wrong one, I see. I'm getting error messages for both. Happy to add that now...

Comment: Please include the FULL error message.

Comment: You must have a cut and paste problem or something.  The only create_mountain call you have is from a Mountain object, which does not have Turtle parent.  Yet your error message is complaining about a Turtle object.

Comment: I've added the super class in both Cloud and Mountain and that doesn't seem to fix it. The full error message is:                                                                                         File "C:\Users\micah\PycharmProjects\FlappyBird\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    mountain.create_mountain()
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'create_mountain'

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your code into a single file and tossed anything that wasn't applicable to the problem at hand.  It runs fine.  Your problem is not with the code you are showing us, so consider isolating it to a [minimal, workable example (mwe)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that displays the error.

Below is my standalone example rework of your code.  As I said, it ran fine as it was, but afterward I cleaned it up a bit style-wise:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

MOVE_SPEED = 10
MOUNTAIN_START = (400, -83)

class Cloud:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_clouds = []
        self.cloud_speed = MOVE_SPEED

    def create_cloud(self):
        random_chance = randint(1, 40)

        if random_chance == 1:
            if self.all_clouds:
                new_cloud = self.all_clouds[-1].clone()
            else:
                new_cloud = Turtle('circle')
                new_cloud.color('white')
                new_cloud.penup()

            new_cloud.shapesize(stretch_wid=randint(1, 4), stretch_len=randint(4, 7))
            random_y = randint(-70, 175)
            new_cloud.goto(400, random_y)

            self.all_clouds.append(new_cloud)

    def move_clouds(self):
        for cloud in self.all_clouds:
            cloud.backward(self.cloud_speed)

class Mountain:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_mountains = []
        self.mountain_speed = MOVE_SPEED

    def create_mountain(self):
        random_chance = randint(1, 40)

        if random_chance == 1:
            if self.all_mountains:
                new_mountain = self.all_mountains[-1].clone()
            else:
                new_mountain = Turtle('triangle')
                new_mountain.color('tan')
                new_mountain.penup()
                new_mountain.tilt(90)

            new_mountain.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=8)
            new_mountain.goto(MOUNTAIN_START)

            self.all_mountains.append(new_mountain)

    def move_mountains(self):
        for mountain in self.all_mountains:
            mountain.backward(self.mountain_speed)

def run():
    if game_on:
        mountain.create_mountain()
        mountain.move_mountains()

        cloud.create_cloud()
        cloud.move_clouds()

        screen.update()
        screen.ontimer(run, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(800, 400)
screen.bgcolor('light blue')
screen.title("FloppyBird")
screen.tracer(0)

mountain = Mountain()
cloud = Cloud()

game_on = True

run()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this. Do you have any idea why this wasn't working with OOP? As I said, it worked fine like 3 days ago, and troubleshooting it went over my head as a beginner.